# R assign list variables to existing strings

Tags: r

I have a vector of string.

```
vec = c("a","b","c")
```

and a list of vectors

```
pr[[1]] = c(1,2,3)
pr[[2]] = c(13,2,3)
pr[[3]] = c(31,27,3)
```

and I want to create a list, so that each variable from my vec-vector will serve as an object and it will be assigned a corresponding (index based) values from pr.
so, in fact I want to to this automatically:

```
list("a" = pr[[1]], "b" = pr[[2]], "c"=pr[[3]])
```

Somehow, I am not getting how I can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
(names(pr) <- vec)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
pr
# $a
# [1] 1 2 3
# $b
# [1] 13  2  3
# $c
# [1] 31 27  3
```